# should the domain be limited for squared fractions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I'm working through a practice exam and one question asks for the domain of

$\frac{1}{(x-4)^2}+3$

and says that the answer is $[1,4)$

I can see that there is an asymptote at $x=4$, and that the range is restricted because the fraction can only evaluate to positive numbers, but why isn't the domain just all real numbers excluding 4?

Comment: can you give more context? is it a multiple choice question?

Comment: okay I'm embarrassed, I'm working from a photo of the question and I just realised that the domain is provided as part of the question (although half cropped out of the photo). They must just be confirming understanding of the notation by asking this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to note about functions is that they are only well-defined if it is clear what the domain is. This means that every time we define a new function $f$, we should really say something like

> Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\mapsto\mathbb{R}$ defined by
> $f(x)=x^2$ for all $x$.

This is too verbose for a working mathematician, and so this sentence often becomes

> Consider the function $f$ defined by $f(x)=x^2$.

or simply

> Consider the function $f(x)=x^2$.

While the latter two sentences are convenient, this convenience is at the cost of logical precision. The domain of a function is part of the definition of the function itself, and the function is $f$, not $f(x)$.

Because of the shorthand that mathematicians adopt, there is a strong convention that, unless otherwise specified, the domain of a function is the set of values for which a formula makes sense. Hence, people tend to say 'the domain of $x^2$ is $\mathbb{R}$'.

In your example, if no further information was given, then we would assume that the domain of the function $f$ given by
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-4)^2}+3
$$
is $x\neq4$. However, since the author has explicitly stated that the domain $[1,4)$, then the domain is quite clearly *not* $x\neq4$.